# Is not faith a prerequisite to argue on matters of faith

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are questions from atheists welcome here?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/are-questions-from-atheists-welcome-here)

On 'Christianity SE' as it stands, do atheist have the right to question and offer their  comments on matter of faith.

Comment: This has already been dealt with in [Are questions from atheists welcome here too?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/493/are-questions-from-atheists-welcome-here) and in [The role of the non-believer on this site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64/the-role-of-the-non-believer-on-the-site). In those places and in others, the community consensus is that atheists are welcome here so long as their questions and answers adhere to our rules.

Comment: The “rules” are some time bent like in this http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/should-adherence-to-official-doctrines-be-the-only-judge-of-quality and http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/461/atheism-is-the-default-position-isnt-the-burden-of-proof-on-the-christian-to-a/1337#1337 as was pointed out by Monika.

Comment: As DJClayworth said in [his comment](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/should-adherence-to-official-doctrines-be-the-only-judge-of-quality#comment3137_1287), the problem there is the question, which currently has 2 close votes. That question/answer combo is also from over a year ago, in the early, early days of Christianity.SE.

Comment: I say earnestly that I no longer and never bothered about it; the “downvote” is it because it is a duplicate or something else has influenced it?

Comment: I up voted because it is a question worth raising. Öf choose it has already been raised and addressed so I voted to choose too. I would guess the down votes are because the title is leading rather than just a question so people use their meta style votes to disagree. That our lack of research effort.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1167?m=6405032#6405032

Answer (score -5):

An atheist cannot  interfere in a process where there is dissemination of questions and answers pertaining to a faith and belief system. This would be like a mathematician asking for a mathematcal model of God, when given an answer based on faith. Considering the position of unbelief and utter faithlessness of an atheist in that which a  faithful considers to be beyond comprehension and give no scientific explanation for existence of God, how an atheist who depends his very existence on lack of faith in God, argue a point of faith. There seems to be no sense in this and it is freely practiced on this site. Just because this site is run by a secular entity does not mean that any one can force his way on others just beacause they are in posion to do so. CSE is an entirely seperate domain for Christian views ONLY and secular trait of main secular site cannot be applied to it and that is the reason I believe it is branched  seperately from main stachexchange which is  run by secularist and there can be views only from a person having 'faith'  on CSE not otherwise. Why don't atheist confine to their own site where they are free to air their views without hurting anyones beliefs..

Comment: Having been an atheist once, my beliefs aren't in much danger of being hurt. Personally, I think a few Christians could stand to do some more critical view of our own beliefs, both to separate the wheat from the chaff, and to make us better able to evangelize to the atheist and agnostic. Christians that can't address the foolish arguments thrown at us effectively make us look ignorant. Nothing hardens steel like tempering through fire, and a challenge to our own preconceptions should, if God is true, strengthen our faith, not hurt it.